# How do I save editorjs json output in a database and handle it on the server side in my node App?

Tags: javascript, editorjs

```
saveButton.addEventListener('click',()=>{ 
    editor.save()
    .then((savedData)=>{          
 })
```

> I'm trying to make the click button submit the data to the database.

Comment: Well you need to send it somehow to the server, look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch. At the server you have to parse the data and insert into your db. which database do you have server side?

Comment: MongoDB, that's the server side db